# Duplicated favorite questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I've noticed that I have duplicated favorite questions after favoriting the same question through web app (in safari) and iOS app. The result is in attachements

> [image: screenshot]

- App Version: 1.4.3.7
- Device: iPhone 5s (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.2.1 (Build 13D15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.4.1, shipping in February.

The app had some wonky code for dealing with a caching bug on the server, so I took out the wonky code and fixed the caching on the server.