# Favorite questions not saving offline

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, bookmarks, offline

I switched to Airplane mode and here is what I get on opening a favorite question:

> [image: On opening a favorite question offline]

It does show the question title, but not the question body and the answers, [as it should](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234296/245360).

Also, a favorite questions shows itself twice in the favorite questions list in the favorite questions tab:

> [image: Dilemma: Two options to open one favorite question]

- App Version: 1.4.3.7
- Device: iPhone 6 (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 9.3 (Build 13E5225a)

Comment: The error message clearly says what is wrong, you were unable to load the website, because you didn't have one due to airplane mode which disables those devices.  I suggest you disable airplane mode to solve your "problem"

Comment: @Ramhound the app is supposed to be able to save favorited questions offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will be fixed in 1.4.4.6, going to the review queue today.

The favorite questions were getting saved and loaded, the question view controller just wasn't getting notified that the data existed.  A casualty of the big refactoring.

[Duplicate questions will also be fixed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273685/duplicated-favorite-questions)

Comment: I downloaded the app today and I still get the same bug shown above. The favorites aren't downloaded automatically for offline use. What a great feature this would be.